# How can i display error if i use subprocess in python

Tags: python, subprocess

I am using subprocess like this

```
args = ['commandname', 'some args']
subprocess.check_output(args)
```

sometimes i get this error

`command returned non-zero exit status 1`

is there any way that if get non zero exit status then the system raise the exception with that message like

```
output = subprocess.check_output(args)
if non zero exit :
   raise Exception(errormessage)
```

Comment: `subprocess.check_output` *already* raises an exception with that message, though. Do you want to raise one with the output of your command instead?

Comment: yes , i want to display the exact error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `subprocess` attribute called `returncode` [[docs]](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.returncode)

```
Popen.returncode 
  The child return code, set by poll() and wait() (and indirectly by communicate()). 
  A None value indicates that the process hasn’t terminated yet.

  A negative value -N indicates that the child was terminated by signal N (Unix only).
```

So it should work something like this (not tested code) -

```
import subprocess
args  = ['commandname', 'some args']
child = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
streamdata = child.communicate()[0]
returncode = child.returncode
if returncode != 0:
    raise Exception
```